# spring boot include OneToMany association in json response

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have an entity

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Date createdAt;

    @NotNull
    private String text;

    @NotNull
    private Date updatedAt;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

and another entity

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Date createdAt;

    @NotNull
    private String text;

    @NotNull
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

and I have a simple controller that returns post json given id

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/posts")
    public class ProductDimensionsController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Post getPost(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id) throws ApiException {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I am getting in response:

```
{
"id": 401,
"createdAt": 1482364510614,
"updatedAt": 1482364510614,
"text": "abc",
}
```

I want follwing:

```
{
"id": 401,
"createdAt": 1482364510614,
"updatedAt": 1482364510614,
"text": "abc",
"comments": [{
    "id": 101,
    "createdAt": 1482364510614,
    "updatedAt": 1482364510614,
    "text": "xyz",
    }]
}
```

How can I include associated OneToMany entities in the json response?

Comment: In case you need some more clarification, please ask in comments. I'll respond in the morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the result you want, you will have to mark the `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` on the `Comment` entity. This will result in fetching the results in `FetchType.LAZY` mode.

Another approach could be:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Date createdAt;

    @NotNull
    private String text;

    @NotNull
    private Date updatedAt;

    @OneToMany
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @JsonIgnore
    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

Comment: ManyToOne has @Target(value={METHOD,FIELD})...which means I cannot mark my comment entity class as @ManyToOne.

Comment: @riship89 you can also add `@JsonIgnore` to `getComments` and `@JsonProperty` on the setter

Comment: I don't understand it very well...how can I mark by `class Comment` with @ManyToOne if @ManyToOne is field level annotation.

Comment: I want to include comments not exclude.

Comment: @riship89 just try what I have just posted. It's late and I'm tired. Code goes better

Comment: @riship89 happy to help